# How did Microsoft get away with JScript?

Tags: history, programming

How exactly did Microsoft reverse engineer Brendan Eich's JavaScript, call it something else and not get a massive lawsuit in the aftermath? I understand this was a long time ago but I still wonder how such a blatant rip-off did not result in massive litigation?

Comment: To laze to write my own answer again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135203/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jscript

Comment: @UncleBod except that JScript was released before ECMAScript was a thing. (Although presumably Netscape knew, when JScript was released, that they would be pushing ECMAScript, so suing wouldn’t have made much sense.)

Comment: Nevertheless, Javascript is an outward-facing language hacked together in a week so Netscape presumably fully documented it from the start? That'd undercut the suggestion that any reverse engineering was involved.

Answer (score 4):

How come there are C compilers not written by Bell Labs?  ;-)

As far as I am aware, there is no prohibition on producing your own implementation of a programming language based on the description of that programming language.

You can't copy someone else's implementation without their permission.

You don't need to reverse-engineer an implementation if there is a description of what the language constructs are intended to do; and with a programming language there almost always is such a description (otherwise there's not much point to it).

Comment: The jury's still out on that; Oracle's attempt to sue Google over Google's reimplementation of parts of Java and whether the API symbols, etc, can be considered copyrightable material, was due to return again to the US Supreme Court last week before COVID-19 threw a spanner in the calendar.

Comment: Ha, I thought that was settled. I see not. Thanks. I don't think that case changes the broad outline of my answer *yet*,

Answer (score -2):

Javascript became a standard known as EMCA Script, and Microsoft's implementation of it was JScript.

Comment: It looks like JScript predates ECMAscript by 15 months though? That said, it was also Netscape who were keen to create a standard as quickly as possible, so I really don't think even Netscape would think that Microsoft had done anything dishonest in attempting to implement the same standard even before its formalisation.

Comment: @user, JScript was released before JavaScript became ECMAScript (or at least, before ECMAScript was published).

Comment: Before it was ratified as a standard. It's common for implementations to precede the standard.

Comment: But you’re saying that JScript is Microsoft’s implementation of the standard; if that’s true, it can’t have preceded the standard.